# Spark Streaming Checkpointing throws S3 exception

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I'm using a S3 bucket in region eu-central-1 as a checkpoint directory for my spark streaming job.

It writes data to that directory but every 10th batch fails with the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4040.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4040.0 (TID 0, 127.0.0.1, executor 0): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request
```

When this happens, the batch data is lost. How can I solve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an authentication exception with the bucket in eu-central-1 because that S3 zone uses the V4 authentication.

It was configured on the driver itself but not on the workers so that's why some worked and some didn't.